# What's the japanese word for "take off" which in romaji sounds similar to "hashin"?

Tags: translation

In many japanese sci fi series (Yamato, Macross, etc.) when a spaceship is going to take off they say something similar in romaji to "hashin!" . When I look for how to say ***take off*** in japanese I find words like 飛び立つ (Tobitatsu ), 踏み切る (Fumikiru ) , but nothing similar to "hashin". How does exactly this word sounds (romaji/hiragana) and how do you write it with kanjis? You can listen it here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4phT2Vukvn0&t=1m16s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's **発進｛はっしん｝** that means indeed "take off / launch / departure".

To break it down, you can see how this word is composed by the kanji 発 (that means departure) which you can indeed find in many related words, and the kanji 進 that means to advance, progress.

Comment: @macky 「は」を ja と書かれたのはスペイン語を話す人だからじゃないですかね

Comment: 発 seems to at its core mean something like 'sudden forward movement'; with quite a bit of variability in particular words.

Comment: in my language (spanish) hashin sounds like jashin. If I have to write the pronunciation for a spanish person of the english word hashin, I would write it jashin, hashin pronounced in spanish sounds like ashin for us.

Comment: BTW, I can't tell the difference in pronunciation between hashin and hasshin.

Comment: @Pablo it's hard to explain in writing. I suppose you don't have double consonants in Spanish? In Italian we do so for me it's easy to understand and feel that difference. Maybe think of the English word "dropping". There are two p there, try to pronounce "droping" instead (such as in "I was at the club droping a girl after sipping on bacardi") and you might be able to feel the difference. With hasshin/hashin is quite the same thing.

Comment: The only double consonant I can recall right now in Spanish it's double r. For example arremeter. We dont have double s or double p